# Chain of Responsibility Design pattern implementation with starting stopping the chain in different points

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have simple implementation of Chain of Responsibility Design pattern which
traversing the chain from the start to end of the chain, but now I want to make
the chain start from a certain point and ends at certain point.

For Example here is a simple pattern implementation in JAVA, 
here I want to the chain stop in B, what is the best way to implement it ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlanetHandler chain = setUpChain();
        //Stop in B dont continue to C
        chain.handleRequest(TypeEnum.B);

}


public enum TypeEnum {
    A, B, C;
}

public abstract class Handler {
    Handler successor;
    public void setSuccessor(Handler successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    public abstract void handleRequest(TypeEnum t);
}


public class A extends Handler {

    public void handleRequest(TypeEnum t) {     
            if (successor != null) {
                successor.handleRequest(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B extends Handler {

    public void handleRequest(TypeEnum t) {     
            if (successor != null) {
                successor.handleRequest(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class C extends Handler {

    public void handleRequest(TypeEnum t) {     
            if (successor != null) {
                successor.handleRequest(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Handler setUpChain() {
        Handler a = new A();
        Handler b = new B();
        Handler c = new C();
        a.setSuccessor(b);
        b.setSuccessor(c);
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Add the corresponding `TyepEnum` to each class and Add a condition that will stop when they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, return something from `handleRequest`. This way you can check if request was handled by the handler or not, and if not, pass it to the next handler. How about something like this:

```
public abstract class Handler {

    Handler successor;

    public void setSuccessor(Handler successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    public boolean handleRequestInChain(TypeEnum t) {
        boolean handled = handleRequest(t);

        if (handled) {
            return true;
        } else if (successor != null) {
            return successor.handleRequestInChain(t);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean handleRequest(TypeEnum t);
}
```

Then construct the chain, and pass the request to it's head's `handleRequestInChain`.

Comment: I not quite understand how does handleRequest(t) knows that i need to stop in B ? 
you see the chin element should be generic and only the handleRequestInChain(t) should make it stop

Comment: handleRequest doesn't know. It's sole purpose is to handle the request and return true, or not handle it and return false. It's abstract Handler that decides that handling should stop, and it does it in handleRequestInChain

Comment: it would be better to make handleRequest PROTECTED.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handler chain = PlanetHandler.setUpChain();
        //Stop in B dont continue to C
        chain.handleRequest(TypeEnum.B);
    }
}



enum TypeEnum {
    A, B, C;
}

abstract class Handler {
    Handler successor;
    public void setSuccessor(Handler successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    public final void handleRequest(TypeEnum t) {
        switch(t) {
        case C: break;
        default: handle(t); break;  
        }
    }

    public abstract void handle(TypeEnum t);
}


class A extends Handler {

    public void handle(TypeEnum t) {     
        if (successor != null) {
            System.out.println("Handling A");
            successor.handleRequest(t);
        }
    }

}

class B extends Handler {

    public void handle(TypeEnum t) {     
        if (successor != null) {
            System.out.println("Handling B");
            successor.handleRequest(t);
        }
    }

}

class C extends Handler {

    public void handle(TypeEnum t) {     
        if (successor != null) {
            System.out.println("Handling C");
            successor.handleRequest(t);
        }
    }
}

class PlanetHandler {

public static Handler setUpChain() {
    Handler a = new A();
    Handler b = new B();
    Handler c = new C();
    a.setSuccessor(b);
    b.setSuccessor(c);
    return a;
}

}
```

It basically implements a general handle function in the abstract class where it is managed the actual control on the handling (see the switch case above).

Comment: no its not dynamic , some time i what it to stop in F ( if i had chain until F or more )